# ¿Como enviar un JSON via una solicitud 'Post' desde mi app Android? - Android

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, postman

Estoy completamente fuera de mi zona con lo que es `PHP` y `Backend`.

Estoy trabajando las notificaciones de una app `Xamarin.Android` y encontre un metodo para enviar notificaciones via `FCM` con `Postman` pero no se como implementar esto desde la app.

En Postman solo es necesario configurar 3 elementos indispensables:

> Header: `APIKEY`
> .

> Body (Notification): `Title` y `Body`.

De este modo:

```
{
    "to": "ID_TOKEN (Opcional)",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Titulo de Ejemplo",
        "body": "Notificacion de ejemplo"
    }
}
```

Al pasarle los 3 parámetros en Postman solo clicamos el boton "`Enviar`".

**Pero, ¿Como hago esto desde una app? ¿Como inyecto este desde una URL?**

Cualquier info servira. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Editado para una mejor comprensión.

Comment: Mira la librería Retrofit y para enviar un json en un post, usa el tag @Body como parámetro del objeto que quieres pasar. Como bonus una vez lo tengas, mira los interceptos y en este enlace tienes la respuestahttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request